# Change control center in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some `label` "my text".
I have some `UserControl`, inside it have text ("text part") and some visual part near text.

Left picture is what i want to achieve. Right is what i got.

I want center my `UserControl` not by its default center but by custom point.
Because "my text" may vary in length, meanwhile it should be centered relative to my controls "text part" center.

[image]

Goal ^                                                                                                                                 Current ^

Comment: Please post the codes you have tried for others to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: snapshot]

You will need to define separate columns, one which is centered for your centered texts, and another one for your visual label.

The tricky part now is synchronizing one column from within the UserControl with one outside of it. You can use SharedSizeGroups for this, like in this example, I just used a ContentControl instead of the UserControl for convenience:

```
   <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="colLeft"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="colRight"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">MyText</Label>
  </Grid>
  <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="colLeft"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="colRight"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Lime">text part a little longer
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1">someVisualLabel</Label>
     </Grid>
  </ContentControl>
```